# pylint, pandas : Comparison to True should be just 'expr' or 'expr is True' (singleton-comparison)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pylint

did anyone solve this pylint issue when using pandas?

```
C:525,59: Comparison to True should be just 'expr' or 'expr is True' (singleton-comparison)
```

this happens in the line where i'm using:

```
df_current_dayparts_raw['is_standard'] == True
```

I tried these but didn't work:

```
df_current_dayparts_raw['is_standard'] is True
df_current_dayparts_raw['is_standard'].isin([True])
df_current_dayparts_raw['is_standard'].__eq__(True)
```

Comment: I think this is a bug in pylint, you should report it to https://github.com/pycqa/pylint.

Comment: I've encountered this issue too.  My work around was to switch from `False`/`True` booleans to `0`/`1` but that won't be an option in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

If you have instantiate a dataframe with the following code

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"bool": [True, False, True], "val":[1,2,3]})
>>> test
    bool  val
0   True    1
1  False    2
2   True    3
```

the following should only return the fields where "bool" is True

```
test[test['bool']]

   bool  val
0  True    1
2  True    3
```

You do not need to explicitly state that test['bool'] == True, test['bool'] should be enough. This should be pylint compliant and satisfy singleton-comparison.

Comment: This is precisely what I needed, thanks!
It makes only sense to use the boolean column as is instead of carrying out a bit-wise comparison on top.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but maybe this will be useful for someone. This worked for me:

```
if df_current_dayparts_raw['is_standard']:
    print("True")
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of `<your_expr> == True`, try `numpy.equal(<your_expr>, True)` . Concretely:

```
import numpy as np
np.equal(df_current_dayparts_raw['is_standard'], True)
```